# Writing more than one command in the Visual Studio 2010 pre-build events field when the commands are not batch files and contain macros

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, pre-build-event, prebuild

I want to execute more than one pre-build event in Visual Studio. But Visual Studio takes all the text in the pre-build events field and executes it as one single command line function, unless you were calling a bunch of batch files. In the case of batch files, you can prefix the word `call` in front of each batch file and put all of them in separate lines and Visual Studio will call each of them.

But the commands I want to execute are not batch files. They are invocations of EXEs with parameters that contain Visual Studio pre-build event macros.

For e.g. like so:

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EdmGen.exe" 
/nologo /language:CSharp /mode:ViewGeneration 
"/inssdl:$(TargetDir)School.ssdl" 
"/incsdl:$(TargetDir)School.csdl" 
"/inmsl:$(TargetDir)School.msl" 
"/outviews:$(ProjectDir)School.Views.cs"
```

That's just one pre-build event. I've added line-breaks only for readability. The real pre-build event does not have line breaks in it.

I want to have several of those in one pre-build event.

Comment: Can't you pass one big arg to one batch file (resolving macros) and then just put %1 in your batch?

Comment: or %1 %2 if one arg, and %1 %2 %3 if two args, and so on.

Comment: or go with the full list up to %9 (will do nothing with blank args)